# What is this effect with blue and yellow color shifts around objects?

Tags: effect

What is this effect with blue and yellow color shifts around objects? How can it be achieved?

[image: blue-shift sample image]

Comment: @xiota Instead of editing a "filter" question to what *you think* the OP is concerned with, it is probably preferable to point the OP to the [relevant questions in meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4944/15871) and **let the OP** define what it is about the photo they wish to replicate. This has been the accepted practice used by the community for this type of question for a long time.

Comment: Yeah, because otherwise you go to lengths answering about what you think is wanted and then "Oh, I just mean the black background", or "why is the car shiny when it's dark".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Blue Channel has been shifted to the left.** This can be confirmed by shifting it back to the right. Some artifacts are left over the from original shift and low quality setting the image was saved at.

Any reasonably good image editor can be used to manipulate the color channels.

[image: shift blue back]