# How to get this purple haze effect?

Tags: photoshop, effect

What effect is used to get this purple type of hazy colour? I am not talking about the green, but only the purple look, where you are almost seeing an item twice. I understand that the blue colour got shifted, however how is this hazy purple achieved.

[image]

Comment: @flolilolilo It's not just you, definitely been here before. Probably been cleaned up by the automated removal now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this effect with blue and yellow color shifts around objects?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100530/what-is-this-effect-with-blue-and-yellow-color-shifts-around-objects) -- with a different color channel.

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: I posted a few days ago, but my question was not clear enough, so i got no helpful answers.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing how this purple effect was achieved. I understand that the blue colour got shifted, however how is this hazy purple achieved.

Comment: I think it would help to put the specific question in the title. Imagine how many completely different questions could have the title you've chosen.

Comment: @mattdm (Hopefully) done.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about the color-separated doubled areas, like this:

[image: circles]

right?

It's pretty hard to really tell with a low resolution, very low quality sample where the center has been scribbled over. But my guess is that this is a post-processing digital effect meant to roughly simulate exaggerated [chromatic aberration](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/is-this-chromatic-aberration), which causes different wavelengths of light to align differently.

Again, it's hard to tell, but I suspect that what this filter did is

1. simply separate red, green, and blue color channels,
2. apply some scaling or transform to those channels separately, and
3. recombine.

Or, it might be as simple as running a 2D image through a "create stereo image filter". There's one in [gmic](https://gmic.eu/), and here's a very quick demonstration using an image from this site's [image of the week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame-2014-archive) (original by [VonsShnauzer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26086/vonschnauzer) on [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vonschnauzer/3672814850/)).

We start with:

[image: original]

and then

[image: gmic]

giving us

[image: "3D"]

... so maybe that's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

That purple haze is most likely done by deliberately (accidentally?) using a "wrong" white balance (WB).

[image: Composite of a "proper" WB (left) and the same picture with thrown-off WB (right).]

Composite of a "proper" WB (left) and the same picture with thrown-off WB (right). <sub>"proper" = "most probably not 100% accurate, but to my personal liking".</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

1. Use the Instagram (or whatever) "filter".
2. Scribble green over face.

**Method 2:**

1. Using state-of-the-art cell-phone-camera technology from two decades ago, take a badly composed selfie in low light – with total disregard for white balance, as [noted by flolilolilo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/105311/75526).
2. Shift the color channels, as [described by mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/105145/75526).
3. Scribble green over face.

**Method 3:**

1. Shift the color channels. (I "borrowed" [mattdm's work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioJeF.jpg).)
2. Blur the image.
3. Add noise.
4. Create a new layer filled with gray, low opacity (~3%).
5. Create a new layer filled with purple, color blending, opacity to taste.
6. Scribble green over face. (I skipped this step.)

[image: purple haze]

Not "hazy" enough? Wrong shade of purple? Go back to method 1.